# How to know on which LAN a machine is connected?

Tags: linux, ip, arp, lan

I have two LANs (192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24) linked by VPN.
I have one machine (RPI3b+) that I can be connected on the first or the second LAN (I move it).

How can I know where is the machine or, rather, how the machine can know where it is ?
Each LAN has a router.

I cannot use ping because ping "see" the second LAN through the VPN.
I note that the ARP table cumulates the both LAN.

I tried:

```
ip -4 neighbor show
```

But the both LAN are shown (because of arp) !

Rgds,

Note 1: I don't use DHCP, only static addressees

Comment: Do the LANs have DHCP enabled on them? If yes, then you can simply check the IP address that has been assigned to the machine by DHCP - you will see to which LAN it belongs.

Comment: No DHCP, I forgot to tell it

Comment: What is your goal? To automatically configure it to the right address when it's moved? Then just use DHCP, or you'll end up reinventing it.

Comment: @A.B No, only to create mounts according to the location

Comment: ARP tables cumulates. The tunnel is a layer 2 tunnel rather than a layer 3 tunnel?

Comment: @A.B: Openvpn. I dont use l2tp

Comment: openvpn in layer 2 mode or layer 3 mode?

Comment: Mode ip then layer 3 no ?

Comment: TUN = layer 2 ?

Comment: tuntap in tun mode with an interface name typically named tun0 is layer 3, tuntap in tap mode is layer 2. But I realize I'm not really able to help enough because I don't understand the setup or the remark in the question about arp. Many things depend on the tunnel endpoints routers (eg: using proxy ARP?)